# Really slow upload/cast compared to smartphones and other laptops in the same network

Tags: wireless, intel, 20.04, connection, plex

I really wanted to cast videos to my Google Chromecast, but I'm facing a really slow connection that doesn't occur with other devices in the same network.
For example I'm trying to send stuff from Plex and it doesn't start or it hiccups really often, but if I navigate and I choose the same files from smartphone or another laptop and I cast them, it works like a charm.

I'm talking about casting as I didn't face slow internet connection before, just because my internet provider offers a really slow upload itself and I didn't notice it in other ways.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 but I also had this problem on older versions.
I tried to add `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=2` (but also 1 and 8) in `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` without results. I also tried to disable the iwconfig power management with `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off` and to turn off the TLP power saving stuff, but nothing helps.
Please send help, I'm going mad.

`iwconfig` result:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TIM-29088207"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: A6:91:B1:BB:D9:D8   
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:684   Missed beacon:0

ham0      no wireless extensions.
```

`lshw -C network` result:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 78
       serial: f8:94:c2:e6:3b:4c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-29-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 ip=192.168.1.250 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:127 memory:ef100000-ef101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: ham0
       serial: 7a:79:19:90:f2:d9
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full ip=25.144.242.217 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Lenovo P53. Wifi was working, but very slowly. I was using the **backport-iwlwifi-dkms** driver. Deinstalling it with `sudo apt-get purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` and rebooting solved it for me.

Be sure to be close to a ethernet cable in case that doesn't work as expected and you have to reinstall the driver.

Comment: I'm using that backport driver too. But unluckily I haven't any ethernet port. I hope I can eventually connect to USB tethering, so I can try...

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same. with or without that driver.